# Where is the source file for commands in /etc/init.d

Tags: 12.04, etc

I am completely new to ubuntu and all commands. I can see list of things inside `etc/init.d`.

I have `hadoop-hdfs-namenode` in my `/etc/init.d`. I want to edit the source file of that command so that i can make it running in the background always? I want to run it like `while true; do sleep 1000; done`. I am using docker `CMD [/usr/start.sh]` inside start.sh i am running `/etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode start`.

If i am making any mistake, please direct me to right way.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be writing a bash script 
`#! /bin/bash
hadoop-hdfs-namenode;
exit;`
Then scheduling the script with [crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto), so it will run on "background".